# No Sound Output from USB DAC Shanling UP2 in 20.04

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio

The USB DAC is getting detected and also able to select in the Sound Settings, but the audio test with left and right not working

[image]

Changing to Analog also didn't help

[image]

In alsamixer, the usb card is detetected and switching to that shows only one control and it is not muted.

[image]

[image]

The same usb dac was working without any issues in MacOS BigSur

Comment: Is it always like this, or just happens sometimes? In other words, does a reboot fix it (sometimes)?

Comment: @Levente, Tried rebooting, also killing pulseaudio and restarting pulseaudio.

Comment: @Levente, I got this a couple of days ago. It was working fine in my work laptop(MBP with BigSur) and just tried it in my personal Desktop and found this issue. I went through other threads and tried restarting pulseaudio, checking if it is mute in AlsaMixer and also tried to see if something is wrong in Pavucontrol as well.

Comment: I have a similar problem using Shaling UA 1 Pro yet it was working before! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1490874/no-sound-using-shanling-ua1-pro-dac-on-ubuntu-22-04-3

Comment: @WMRamadan , the issue is still there at least when I have checked few months ago. It stopped charging now, I should have bought DAC/AMP from FIIO.

Comment: @WMRamadan, I thought my UP2 is dead, turns out it is charging only when I use Type-A to Type-C cable. Type-C to Type-C charging isn't working.