# No Sound using Shanling UA1 Pro DAC on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio

I have a Shanling UA1 Pro DAC which I have been using for about 1 year on Ubuntu 22.04 without any problems. The sound was working find until one day I updated my system and the sound stopped working.

The DAC shows and is listed in my audio devices. Pulse audio is working fine and there seems to be no error messages.

I have tried reinstalling the pulse-audio and I have tried other USB DAC's which work OOTB.

This problem seems to have happened once I upgraded my Ubuntu Installation. I have also tried this DAC on another computer using my Thinkpad P16S and it will not work either which also has an installation of Ubuntu 22.04.3. Yet when I tried this same DAC with my Windows 11 PC it works without problems. I have also tried it on my M1 MacBook Air without any problems.

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Comment: Yea I have mention that there are no error messages that I can see. Do you have any pointers on specific logs I should look at?